# How to pack own code and external jar s and dll s together in a folder

Tags: java, classpath, lwjgl

I wrote a little 3D game in java, using the LWJGL. So far, I put my necessary .jars in the (jre//jdk/jre)/lib/ext/ directories and the .dlls in the (jre//jdk)/bin/ directories which works fine as long as I am not trying to run my game on another machine.

Now I want to create a own single folder which contains all the .dlls, .jars, resources and of course my own separate .jar file with the main-Method.

My question is how I can achieve it that the only thing I need to run my program is that single folder and yet be able to run the game by double-clicking the main-jar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is an easier solution to your problem, use this link: http://ninjacave.com/jarsplice and download the program. It will create 1 single jar that will run everywhere.(If Java and the correct version of LWJGL are installed)

Comment: I already thought about this, but I want to be completely independent of any external licenses except that of LWJGL.

Comment: I understand, what do you already know about copying files? For the copying, you could write your own code or use the links on this page: http://www.lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Distributing_Your_LWJGL_Application

Comment: I tried it, but now it looks like my own jar file is able to see the external ones, but the external ones are not able to see each other.

Comment: That link was the solution I searched for and now it runs how I imagined.  http://www.lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Distributing_Your_LWJGL_Application

Comment: Ah, I'm glad I could help! And good luck further programming in LWJGL!